# Scoring System for 501 darts in Adobe Flash cs6

Tags: flash

My current project shows a dartboard, when clicked it returns a value to the txt symbol. I'm trying to get the scoring system down before I venture to animations and user input.
 file link below
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxecISV9lD7CZDNVSTFoZHA2RlU

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkDart);
function checkDart(e:Event):void{
    //get mouse coordinates
    var xm:Number = this.mouseX;
    var ym:Number = this.mouseY;
    //assume we missed
    var s:int = 0;
    //check bullseye
    if(bullseye_mc.hitTestPoint(xm, ym, true)){
        s = 50;
    }else{
        //check sectors
        for(var n:int = 1; n <= 20; n++){
            if(this["s" + n].hitTestPoint(xm, ym, true)){
                s = n;
            }
         }
         if(triple_mc.hitTestPoint(xm, ym, true)){
             s = s * 3;
         }else if(double_mc.hitTestPoint(xm, ym, true)){
             s = s * 2;
         }
    }
    var t:String = String(s);
    txt.text = t;
}
```

I did take this code from a source on the internet and the only modification I have made is making `s = s x 3` for a triple and `s = s x 2` for a double compared to it saying '[insert s score] DOUBLE' etc.

Anyway, my question is: how would I go about continuously being able to take 's' away from 501 each time an 's' value is returned? I've stared at this problem for the past hour trying possible solutions and have caved to seek help on the internet. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I should of specified, if it wasn't clear already, I want to take s away from 501, return a new value and take s away from that until I'm down to 0. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried running a while s loop in various parts of the code to no avail. Bump.. :( Does anyone know how to use the return function in actionscript 3? If I can return s I will then be able to run it through score = 501 - s and loop it.

Comment: Ahh bump. Still haven't resolved this issue. Thinking of handing in this project as a completely animated dart game that simply tells the player what score they hit on the dart board.. lol